# K-Means for topic modelling - Elbow method

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using K-Means for extracting topics from text. I know it is not the best way but this is just one step towards a more complex model. What puzzles me is the elbow curve I get (below). How would you interpret it? Why is there a sudden spike around 50 K? Or the elbow method doesn't really work when dealing with text?

```
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans

wcse = []
for k in range(5, 100, 5):
    kmeans_model = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++', n_init=1, 
                         init_size=1000, batch_size=1000, verbose=False, max_iter=1000)
    kmeans = kmeans_model.fit(X) # where X is my data
    wcse.append(kmeans_.inertia_)

#plot it
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(range(5, 100, 5), wcse)
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Elbow curve')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that k-means is not stable on such data.

Run it 10 times with each k, and plot all results.

K-means is sensitive to outliers and high-dimensional data. So it just does not work reliable on text.

Answer (score 0):

How would you define the distance between different topics using k-means?

If you just use similarity of words as a distance metric for k-means you won't get the topics, you get some kind of a word counter.

I'd use Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) for topic modeling, there are easy to use libraries for Python, R, Java..